# In org mode source block, how to prevent lines starting with asterisk being folded?

Tags: org-mode

I want to have a block of verbatim text like

```
output line 0.
* info 0. a53qpb199pb
output line 1.
* info 1. 1iq01a58b39
```

in an org file. I tried putting the text inside `#+BEGIN_SRC` and `#+END_SRC`, but the lines starting with an asterisk (`*`) are folded synchronously when the other headings are folded by SHIFT-TAB or default setting. Sometimes the folding includes the lines beyond `#+END_SRC` and breaks the logical structure of the content. How can I let org mode to treat this block as a purely verbatim object?

My question is related to the following one in StackOverflow:

- [How do I tell org-mode to disable headings in verbatim text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39820332/)

In my case, asterisks inside the source block are not fontified as headings, and they don't function fully as heading of a section. Rather, they behave as headings only with respect to folding by TAB, SHIFT-TAB, and default setting.

I tried adding text, markdown, fundamental specifications next to `#+BEGIN_SRC` without success. I tried `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE` and `#+END_EXAMPLE` without success.

Comment: You "quote" such lines by prepending a `,` to them. See [Literal Examples](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write it as follows:

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
output line 0.
,* info 0. a53qpb199pb
output line 1.
,* info 1. 1iq01a58b39
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

See [Literal Examples](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html) in the manual. The commas are stripped when you export the file; they are also stripped if you edit the block with `C-c '` and are properly reintroduced when you finish the edit (with another `C-c '`).